# Flutter Try removing the code, or fixing the code before it so that it can be reached

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a block of code that I've wanted to try but the start of the code becomes a dead code.

```
Future createGroupChat(
      String groupName, String userName, memberList, memberIDList) async {
    DocumentReference groupDocRef = await groupCollection.add({
      'groupName': groupName,
      'admin': [userName],
      'members': memberList,
      'groupID': '',
    });

    await groupDocRef.update({
      'groupID': groupDocRef.id,
      'members': FieldValue.arrayUnion([userName])
    });

    DocumentReference userDocRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userID);
    return await userDocRef.update({
      'groups': FieldValue.arrayUnion([groupDocRef.id + '_' + groupName])
    });

    DocumentReference memberDocRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(memberIDList);
    return await memberDocRef.update({
      'groups': FieldValue.arrayUnion([groupDocRef.id + '_' + groupName])
    });
  }
```

The dead code starts at `DocumentReference memberDocRef =`. If I move the `DocumentReference memberDocRef` on top of `DocumentReference userDocRef` the `DocumentReference userDocRef` will become dead code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dead code means it can't be reached, when you are returning here `return await userDocRef.update({` then the code below it will never be executed, just remove the first `return`:

```dart
    DocumentReference userDocRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userID);
        await userDocRef.update({
      'groups': FieldValue.arrayUnion([groupDocRef.id + '_' + groupName])
    });

    DocumentReference memberDocRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(memberIDList);
    return await memberDocRef.update({
      'groups': FieldValue.arrayUnion([groupDocRef.id + '_' + groupName])
    });
```